# Audio file only plays first few seconds before restarting on website

Tags: javascript, svelte, vite, cloudflare, firebase-hosting

I am trying to create a small sound dashboard app (similar in functionality to [Noisli](https://www.noisli.com/)). For every "sound" I am using a for loop in Svelte to generate its HTML:

```
    {#each songList as {id, name}}
        <button id="{name}Container" on:click={() => handleSong(name)} class="sound">
            <p class="soundCaption">{name}</p>
            <audio id="{name}" src="/audio/{name}.mp3" loop></audio>
        </button>
    {/each}
```

When the container is clicked it is then handled with this function:

```
    function handleSound(soundName){
        const audio = document.getElementById(soundName);
        const temp = soundName + "Container";
        var audioContainer = document.getElementById(temp);
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            audioContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            audioContainer.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)";
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that on a local dev server the audio works & plays fine, however when I build it (using Vite) and deploy it (using Firebase hosting), the audio clips only play for a few seconds before throwing this error:

```
Media resource https://www.example.com/audio/example-sound.mp3 could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_DECODE_ERR (0x806e0004)
Details: virtual mozilla::MediaResult __cdecl mozilla::FFmpegAudioDecoder<46465650>::DoDecode(mozilla::MediaRawData *, uint8_t *, int, bool *, mozilla::MediaDataDecoder::DecodedData &): FFmpeg audio error
```

Only Firefox gives me this error, however the problem happens in all browsers I've tried (Brave, Vivaldi, Firefox & Edge)

The audio clips work fine if you load them directly on the hosted version too, without any errors (e.g. https://www.example.com/audio/example-sound.mp3)

I have tried re-encoding all of the MP3 files with Audacity to no avail, and simplified all of the code within the handler (previously it would slowly fade sounds in/out etc.).

---

**EDIT:** After a lot of debugging I think the issue is to do with Cloudflare - I'm hosting two live websites on different domains both with this project on, one with Cloudflare and one without, and the one without it works perfectly fine.

---

Comment: I would suggest a component for the button. The querying could then be replaced with `bind:this` and `bind:paused` be used for toggling a class based on the variable. (`<p>` isn't valid inside a button) This is a useful tutorial session when working with multiple audio elements in case you don't know it yet https://svelte.dev/tutorial/module-exports

Comment: Thanks @Corrl, quite new to svelte (if you cant tell lol) so I hadn't got that far in the svelte.dev tutorials yet, but once I get a chance to look through that page I'll post an edit : )